# Markov chain - how calculate the probability to reach a state in $n$ steps?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I'm preparing for an exam and I already know, if you have a transition matrix of a Markov chain given, how to calculate the probability to reach state $A$ from state $B$.

But I don't know how to reach one state in specific steps from another state.

Let's say there is this transition matrix given of a Markov chain:

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4\\ 
0.2 & 0.7 & 0.1\\ 
0.2 & 0.3 & 0.5
\end{pmatrix}$$

On the internet I have found a formula to calculate the probability to reach state $i$ (for the first time) after $n$ steps when you start from $i$:
$$f_{i}^{(n)} = P\left(X_n=i, X_k \neq i \text{ for } 1 \leq k < n \mid X_0=i\right)$$

Or another formula (different site) I found: $$p_{ij}^{k} := P\left[X_{t+k} = j \mid X_t=i\right]=(P^k)_{ij}$$

, the probability to reach state $j$ in exactly $k$ steps starting from state $i$

Buuut I don't really understand anything here... How can I use this formula? :c

Let's say I wanted calculate the probability $f_{02}^{3}$ so to start from state $0$ and reach state $2$ in $3$ steps, how would this be done?
Or some other example (if mine is badly chosen) where I can see how this works please? :/

Comment: $P$ gives you the probability of going from $A$ to $B$ in one step. $P^2$ gives you the probability of going from $A$ to $B$ in two steps. $P^3$....

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understood that but I like to see how the formula is used, some steps of calculating it in detail, some example :)

Comment: Do you understand how $P$ gives you the probability of going from $A$ to $B$ in one step?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Let's say we want from state $0$ to state $1$ in one step. Using the formula above it should be $$(P^1)_{01} = P[X_{t+1}=1 \mid X_t = 0]$$

But what would be the output of that? And I wouldn't know what to set $t$ as either :c

Comment: Is the problem that you don't understand the notation $(P^1)_{01}$? $P^1$ is just $P$, and the subscript means we want the entry in row zero, column one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so that would be $(P^1)_{01}=0.3$, right? What I don't understand is the part after the equals symbol. How would you calculate $(P^2)_{01}$?

Comment: Do you not know how to calculate $P^2$, when $P$ is a $3\times3$ matrix? Is that the problem?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, right. But the way you phrased your comment, I think $(P^2)_{01}$ is calculated this way: Do $P \cdot P$. The value in row zero, column one of this matrix (I mean of $P \cdot P$) is the probability to reach state one from state zero in exactly two steps?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you please confirm if that's right? :)

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thanks so much!! If you like you can put these comments as a (short) answer so I can give you some of my points because that was very important to me to understand. I would like to give you a bounty for that.

Comment: No time now – maybe I'll come back later.